# Smooth curve scatter plots

Tags: r, plot, smoothing

I have two following smooth curve scatter plots in R.

```
plot(lowess(x,y), col="blue")
plot(lowess(a,b), col="red")
```

or

```
qplot(x,y, geom='smooth', span =0.5,col="blue")
qplot(a,b, geom='smooth', span =0.5,col="red")
```

Now I want to merge them to one figure of two curves where the horizontal axis is all values of x and a. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm talking about R

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: there are examples in `?lowess` for this